# With en Python, similar a With en VBA

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba, codificacion

En VBA existe la declaración `With` , con la cual puedo asignar varias propiedades a un mismo objeto en un mismo bloque de código ej:

```
Sub macro()
With range ("A1")
    .Color = Red
    .Bold = True
    .FontStyle = "Arial"
    .Size = 11
End With
```

¿Existe algo similar en Python?, para no tener que escribir varias veces el mismo nombre del objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python tiene una sentencia `with` pero es para entrar en un *contexto* (trozo de código en que debe realizarse algo automáticamente al salir, por ejemplo trozo de código en que se abre un fichero y debe ser cerrado al terminar). Es decir, es para otra cosa.

Una solución muy sencilla para "escribir menos" es asignar temporalmente el nombre del objeto a una variable mucho más corta, por ejemplo `o`:

```
o = objetodenombrelargo
o.Color = Red
o.Bold = True
o.FontStyle = "Arial"
o.Size = 11
```

Vale, sí, hay que repetir `o.` delante de cada atributo, pero no son tantos caracteres (escribir un `with` ya son también cuatro caracteres más).

### Solución *overkill*

Si insistes en tener una sintaxis similar al `with` de VBA, lo más parecido que se me ocurre es lo siguiente.

> *Disclaimer*. Lo escribo porque me ha parecido divertido que se pueda lograr algo bastante cercano sintácticamente en Python, pero no porque considere que sea muy útil.

Definimos la función:

```
def with_(o, **kwargs):
  for k,v in kwargs.items():
    setattr(o, k, v)
```

Y la usaríamos de la siguiente forma:

```
class MiObjeto:
  pass

objeto_mio = MiObjeto()

with_(objeto_mio
    ,Color = "Red"
    ,Bold = True
    ,FontStyle = "Arial"
    ,Size = 11
)
```

Observa cómo he hecho "trampa", cambiando donde iría cada punto por una coma (que en realidad es el separador entre los parámetros que estoy pasando a la función `with_()`

Esa función recibe todos los parámetros en el diccionario `kwargs` por el que itera para ir asignando esos valores al objeto, haciendo uso de `setattr()`.